# Dynamic Spirit parser depending on flag bits

Tags: c++, binary-data, boost-spirit

I'm attempting to build a parser that decides whether to parse fields based on the contents of an initial bit field:

```
rule<Iterator, locals<uint32_t> > r =
    big_dword [_a = _1]
    >> (((_a & 0x01) >> big_dword) | attr(100))
    >> (((_a & 0x10) >> big_dword) | attr(0))
    >> (((_a & 0x80) >> big_qword) | attr(0))
    ;
```

That is, it will only attempt to extract the first field if the LSB is set, and if not, it exposes the default value 100 as the attribute, etc., and so on for the rest of the fields.

(from: [spirit-general](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Dynamic-parser-implementation-question-tc4404809.html) list)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you are making me guess about the actual question.

But I made up a few test cases with 'telling' fallback values. I use karma to format the parse result. For good measure (checking my own sanity, really) I provided both little-endian and big-endian test results.

Hope this helps:

### Code

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

template <typename dword_t, typename qword_t, typename Cases>
void test(const dword_t& dword, const qword_t& qword, const Cases& cases)
{
    typedef boost::tuple<uint32_t,uint32_t,uint32_t,uint64_t> attr_t;
    typedef const char* Iterator;
    int count = 0;

    for (auto testcase : cases)
    {
        Iterator f = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&*testcase.begin());
        Iterator l = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&*testcase.end());
        Iterator b = f;

        qi::rule<Iterator, attr_t(), qi::locals<uint32_t> > r;

        r %=   dword [ qi::_a = qi::_1 ]
            >> (( qi::eps(qi::_a & 0x01ul) > dword) | qi::attr(0x0123ul ))
            >> (( qi::eps(qi::_a & 0x10ul) > dword) | qi::attr(0x0234ul ))
            >> (( qi::eps(qi::_a & 0x80ul) > qword) | qi::attr(0x0345ull))
            ;

        attr_t data;
        bool ok = qi::parse(f,l,r,data);

        std::cout << std::dec    << "testcase "         << count++ << "\t"
                  << "success: " << std::boolalpha      << ok      << "\t"
                  << "parsed: "  << std::distance(b, f) << (f==l?"(complete)\n":"(incomplete)\n")
                  << "\t"        << std::hex            << data    << "\n";
    }
}

typedef std::vector<uint32_t> Input;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "little endian: ";
    test(qi::dword, qi::qword, std::list<Input> { 
            { 0x11110000u, 0x22220000u, 0x44440000u, 0x88880000u, 0x99990000u, },
            { 0x11110001u, 0x22220000u, 0x44440000u, 0x88880000u, 0x99990000u, },
            { 0x11110010u, 0x22220000u, 0x44440000u, 0x88880000u, 0x99990000u, },
            { 0x11110080u, 0x22220000u, 0x44440000u, 0x88880000u, 0x99990000u, },
            { 0x11110011u, 0x22220000u, 0x44440000u, 0x88880000u, 0x99990000u, },
            { 0x11110081u, 0x22220000u, 0x44440000u, 0x88880000u, 0x99990000u, },
            { 0x11110091u, 0x22220000u, 0x44440000u, 0x88880000u, 0x99990000u, },
        });

    std::cout << "\nbig endian: ";
    test(qi::big_dword, qi::big_qword, std::list<Input> { 
            { 0x00001111u, 0x00002222u, 0x00004444u, 0x00008888u, 0x00009999u, },
            { 0x01001111u, 0x00002222u, 0x00004444u, 0x00008888u, 0x00009999u, },
            { 0x10001111u, 0x00002222u, 0x00004444u, 0x00008888u, 0x00009999u, },
            { 0x80001111u, 0x00002222u, 0x00004444u, 0x00008888u, 0x00009999u, },
            { 0x11001111u, 0x00002222u, 0x00004444u, 0x00008888u, 0x00009999u, },
            { 0x81001111u, 0x00002222u, 0x00004444u, 0x00008888u, 0x00009999u, },
            { 0x91001111u, 0x00002222u, 0x00004444u, 0x00008888u, 0x00009999u, },
        });
}
```

### Output

```
little endian: testcase 0   success: true   parsed: 4(incomplete)
    (11110000 123 234 345)
testcase 1  success: true   parsed: 8(incomplete)
    (11110001 22220000 234 345)
testcase 2  success: true   parsed: 8(incomplete)
    (11110010 123 22220000 345)
testcase 3  success: true   parsed: 12(incomplete)
    (11110080 123 234 4444000022220000)
testcase 4  success: true   parsed: 12(incomplete)
    (11110011 22220000 44440000 345)
testcase 5  success: true   parsed: 16(incomplete)
    (11110081 22220000 234 8888000044440000)
testcase 6  success: true   parsed: 20(complete)
    (11110091 22220000 44440000 9999000088880000)

big endian: testcase 0  success: true   parsed: 4(incomplete)
    (11110000 123 234 345)
testcase 1  success: true   parsed: 8(incomplete)
    (11110001 22220000 234 345)
testcase 2  success: true   parsed: 8(incomplete)
    (11110010 123 22220000 345)
testcase 3  success: true   parsed: 12(incomplete)
    (11110080 123 234 2222000044440000)
testcase 4  success: true   parsed: 12(incomplete)
    (11110011 22220000 44440000 345)
testcase 5  success: true   parsed: 16(incomplete)
    (11110081 22220000 234 4444000088880000)
testcase 6  success: true   parsed: 20(complete)
    (11110091 22220000 44440000 8888000099990000)
```